# get mongodb file id before the image is saved using gridfs

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I a new to MongoDb GridFs. I am making an application where I am creating a meeting and uploading files related to the meeting. When I save the entire record, the table must have the meeting id auto generated number and the document id that I receive from the mongodb

```
return gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, documentName, "image/jpeg", metaData).getId();
```

Now, the business require that the file is uploaded asynchronously so that the big file does not hold the page and the user does not have to wait for the upload to complete to submit the page. The problem is, I will not get the document id unless the entire upload is done. But unless I have the id, i cannot save the data with meeting id in the mysql table. 
Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: You need to create `@Async` method to upload your image asynchronously See here [https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/). For `id`, try to add `_id` into your metadata variable. So, you can return id and asynchronously save image in your mongodb

Comment: So you mean that I store meeting id in the metadata variable of the file and then retrieve it from file id and save it in the mysql?

Comment: I mean: Instead of delegate MongoDB generating ID for image, generate it you. This ID will be saved with image content + your meeting in MySQL. You do not need to save ID and retrieve it again. By the way, why do you need to store in MongoDB your image and in MySQL your meeting, have you seen MySQL BLOB to store binnary file?

Comment: I need to save image. Is saving the image in mongodb rather that saving it as mysql blob not a good idea? Performance of mongodb while retrieving the imange seems to be better than mysql blob. Also, mysql will consume more disk space if we talk about thousands of images. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Basically, if your data does not fit in single instance/PC, use distributed db, like MongoDB... For less data, MySQL is more faster, efficient than other NoSQL databases. So, depending on your data size, choose to store in MongoDB or MySQL or mix (persist in MongoDB, use MySQL for transactions, aggregation, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your code to:-

```
return (ObjectId)gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, documentName, "image/jpeg", metaData).getId();
```